# jsp, Servlet reload only form when the page is being submited

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

The project I'm doing is based on Java jsp and Servlets

I'm creating question navigator that navigates to a new question once the submit button is clicked. Shown below is the form I have used in the jsp page.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/QuestionGenerateUser"> 
                            <div class="form-group" id="question">
                                <div class="labelalign">
                                    <label class="radio1" for="answer1">${Question}?</label>
                                    <input type="text" value="${QuestionID}" name="id" id="id" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
                                </div>
                                <label class="labels" ><input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer" value="1" checked="checked">${answer1}</label>
                                <span style="visibility: hidden;" class="error2" id="ans"></span>

                                <span style="visibility: hidden;" class="error2" id="answ1"></span><br>
                                <label class="labels" ><input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer" value="2">${answer2}</label>


                                <span style="visibility: hidden;" class="error2" id="answ2"></span><br>
                                <label class="labels" ><input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer" value="3">${answer3}</label>


                                <span style="visibility: hidden;" class="error2" id="answ3"></span><br>
                                <label class="labels" ><input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer" value="4">${answer4}</label>


                                <span style="visibility: hidden;" class="error2" id="answ4"></span><br>
                            </div>

                            <div style="margin-top: 30px; float: right;" >

                                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submitAnswer" id="submit" value="Next Question" onclick="javascript:callMyMethodToSubmitAjax()"/>

                            </div>
                        </form>
```

This is my servlet code which gets data from classes and sets into the jsp

```
if (request.getParameter("submitAnswer") != null) {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            String id = request.getParameter("id");
            String answer = request.getParameter("answer");
            Answer anAnswer = new Answer(id, answer);

            questionProcessor.addAnswer(anAnswer);
            Question question = questionProcessor.getQuestions();
            request.setAttribute("Question", question.getQuestion());
            request.setAttribute("answer1", question.getAnswer1());
            request.setAttribute("answer2", question.getAnswer2());
            request.setAttribute("answer3", question.getAnswer3());
            request.setAttribute("answer4", question.getAnswer4());
            request.setAttribute("QuestionID", question.getId());
            request.setAttribute("test", null);
            request.setAttribute("submitAnswer", null);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("QuestionPaper.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else if (request.getParameter("getResults") != null) {
            questionProcessor.printResutls();
        }
```

I have a timer in my jsp page where a time count down is being done. How can I refresh only the form once the submit button is clicked. currently it is refreshing the whole page and the timer too resets when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

How about use an HTML iframe which points to a jsp page containing that form? That way, Only your iframe will change when you submit the form and the timer outside will continue to count.

---

a simple example by integrating code from

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_setinterval2

and

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
</script>

<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HI, Sorry i couldn't reply earlier. I tried adding a iframe, but it doesn't display anything. the iframe is blank. can u please try and add an iframe and show me?